# Embeded video in PDF

Tags: video, pdf

I'm creating a presentation that will have embedded video in it (using beamer).

The issue is that I can't make this work on Linux.
I have downloaded some example presentations that contained video, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Acrobat either doesn't do anything, or tries to open some website which only tells me that my system isn't supported.

Okular doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Are there any viewers that can actually work with embedded videos? I'm fine with re-encoding the video in a different format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, the closest-to-working setup is `flashmovie` package used with an `swf`-wrapped movie. And it will only work with Adobe's reader under linux. You'll need to use

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie}
```

at the very **top** of your main TeX-file - it has to be sourced before `beamer`, otherwise other things will break.

Comment: Great, just my luck. The last version of Acroread broke it completely :-D

Comment: But it works great with the previous version.